# How to set "volume: - postgres" Windows 10

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

I'm setting up db. 
But I have problems with some code. How path should looks like?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_USER: user1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: user123
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

after running command `docker-compose up -d`, I would like to create db from "Data source", but I'm getting error. Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIKP.jpg

Also here is output of `docker container ps -a`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c446H.jpg

Comment: what is `db source`? It looks like you have problems with connection but setup seems correct - have you provided right password for your user?

Comment: Sorry I did mistake, I meant "Data source" not "db source"
Here's image: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/aUHwem3.jpg)

Comment: type `docker container ps -a` and edit your question with the output. Also try not to use `-d` option as it will detach from the output. Check logs after launching without `-d` option and post them here.

Comment: So I try without <code>d</code>, but terminal stop at: https://i.imgur.com/RLhdAPK.jpg

And kitematiclog: https://i.imgur.com/V2pNwat.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Docker version, I was using 18.03. On 19.03 works fine!